# How to disable only_full_group_by?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I am facing with problem to disable it. I was looking some explanation step by step,but i can't find. Please anyone can help me about this?

Comment: Don't disable it and write valid SQL queries instead.

Comment: Sorry you mean to write in SQL  right?

Comment: I mean you should write queries that don't violate the rules for aggregations. That way you don't need to disable the setting but have valid queries from a standard SQL (and pretty much every other DBMS than MySQL) point of view. That would be the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can re`set` global variable `@@sql_mode` - but you need to be careful not removing other parameters that could be part of it.

Here is one approach:

```
set global sql_mode = (select replace(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', ''));
```

Note that disabling this sql mode is usually an indication of bad design in some of your queries. I would not actually recommend doing this; instead, you should put more effort into writing queries that comply to the SQL standard as regard to `group by` behavior.

Comment: Ok GMB i really appreciate this help.Now please understand me that i am am newbie here,explain me step by step. Now first i must open Phpmyadmin and go to SQL right?

Comment: @StevenTaylor: yes, exactly, you can run this query in the SQL panel of phpmyadmin.

Comment: Ok after running this query i got error: Error
SQL query: Documentation


set global sql_mode = (select replace(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', ''))
MySQL said: Documentation

#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

Comment: GMB what you think, why i receive this error that i not have privileges? Or what i must  to do to have that privileges?

Comment: @StevenTaylor: yes, that's a permission issue. You can try `set session sql_mode = ...` instead of `set global sql_mode = ...` (you will need to run this command everytime you create a new session).